# How to read multiple files in JMeter random csv data set config

Tags: csv, jmeter

I need to read multiple files in a folder and extract the value from it. I tried random csv data set config but i am able to read only one file.

Example:

c://Testing/test101.csv
c://Testing/test102.csv
c://Testing/test103.csv

1st iteration - c://Testing/test101.csv
2nd iteration - c://Testing/test102.csv
3rd iteration - c://Testing/test103.csv

In above example, each iteration i have to read a single file and take the value from it. May i know how can i achieve it using Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, Random CSV Data Set Config is being initialized **once** when your test starts.

If you want to get data from CSV files using dynamic file names take a look at [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

In case you want a random line take a look at [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which allows executing arbitrary Groovy code, something like:

```
${__groovy(lines = new File('file.csv').readLines();randomLine = lines.get(org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils.nextInt(lines.size())); return randomLine;,)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Sure thanks @Ivan G. I will definitely check it out.